# Where are deployed solutions being used?

Tags: solution-package, stsadm

I'm in a MOSS 2007 environment and am looking to find a way to see where solutions listed in the stsamd -o enumsolutions are activated in site collections.  How would I go aout finding out where these solutions/features are activated down to the site level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preupgradecheck tells you what's wrong, but it doesn't say where the issue lies.  I used the enumallweb stsadm command in conjunction with the -includewebparts and -includesetupfiles switches to enum through all the site collections and subsites to find the offending features and setup files.

For the borken web parts, I could just go to the site listed and append contents=1 to the URL to delete the erred web part.  The output also told me where the missing files were located.  This appears to be a bug from the meeting templates as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839877).  I'm still tracing down a couple web parts and will resort to [querying a backup copy of the database](http://blog.uvm.edu/jgm/2010/08/25/preparing-the-sharepoint-2007wss3-database-for-upgrade/) if I have to.

Answer (score 0):

Solution management in Operations tab of Central Administration can show you which site collections a particular solution has been deployed to, good for one-off queries. Do you need something more "ad-hoc" callable, perhaps by a user without access to Central Admin?

Comment: The solutions in CA are deployed farm wide.  What I'd like to know is where webpart.wsp is actually being utilized at the site level.  So like webpart.wsp is being used at http://domain/mgpath/sitecoll/site1 and http://domain/mgpath/sitecoll/site2/pages/mywebpartpage.aspx for example.

Comment: I think this might actually be a feature of the SharePoint 2007 to 2010 Pre Upgrade Check tool available in STSADM. It's designed to help you scope out your farm before you upgrade to 2010, but it might provide you with the info you need...

Comment: I'll have to take a closer look at that information and see.