# Where are Sandboxed solutions being used?

Tags: 2010, sandbox-solution, best-practices

Within many of our SharePoint 2010 Site Collections, we have the Solution Gallery.  Within these Solution Galleries, there exists Sandboxed solutions that are active and used with each Site Collection.  What is the best way to determine where a Sandboxed solution is used within that Site Collection?

I consulted these other SharePoint stackexchange articles [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/where-are-deployed-solutions-being-used) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25172/how-can-i-determine-which-solutions-and-features-are-being-used-in-a-sharepoin), but they seemed to refer to Farm Features at the Farm Level.  It would be nice to know where Sandbox solutions are used within each Site Collection.  Some of these solutions have 0 resources due to low activity.  I do not want to deactivate each solution and wait for users to complain.  Id rather know via an administrative interface if possible to give me the idea of what impact the solution has on the Site Collection.

Answer (score 0):

Sandboxed solution can implement/automate business use cases that revolves around the data in a particular site. That being said there is no direct way to list the features of such solutions.

Your best bet is to list solutions using PowerShell. Then talk to the developers/site owners who created those.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool on codePlex called [SPmanager](http://spm.codeplex.com/), which will help you to locate the solution i.e. where it is being used.

But it will not tell you what will be the impact if disable a sandbox solution.